# Replace large switchcase by textfile/database[Java]

Tags: java, switch-statement, readfile

In my project, I am working with functions that need to read the ID to get information like which function to call next or to get a unique name for each ID.
So far I have been writing all this information in a switch case statement like below.

```
switch(ID)
{
 case 1: functionA()
 ......
 case 400:  functionZ()
}
```

I would prefer to do this in a textfile or a database where I can access this information and edit it simply like a comma separated file or a SQL database.
also important to say is that this switch case is often used and therefore speed is somewhat important.

my question is what kind of method can be used to replace this.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: which alternatives there are to large switchcases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your switch with a consruction like `Map<Integer, Runnable> actions`. Then you could just `actions.get(id).run()`.

The tricky part is how you initialize this map.

Keys are trivial, you could just define them as is. Values (those `Runnable`s) are tricky. How would you define `functionA` or `functionZ` in serializable form? There may be many options. For instance, you can implement each of the functions as a separate class and then serialize the class name. You could then configure your switch statement in a CSV file like:

```
id,className
1,com.acme.foo.FunctionA
400,com.acme.foo.FunctionZ
```

Where `FunctionX` implements `Runnable` (or any other suitable interface). When loading the CSV file you'd create instances of classes via reflection (`Class.forName(className).newInstance`). Your switch would be as simple as `actions.get(id).run()` (well, some null check would be good).

After initialization this will be pretty fast, you should not see much difference to a switch statement.

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need, I will accept this answer in 1 hour to let other people have the chance to make another suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reflections` to do it too:

Let's you name your functions as function1, function2, ... and they correspond to the IDs 1, 2, ..., etc. Let's also say they don't take any arguments and return void.

```
java.lang.reflect.Method method;
try {
  String methodName = "function" + ID;
  method = obj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
  method.invoke(obj);
} catch (SecurityException e) { ... }
  catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { ... }
```

Here `obj` is the object of the class that contains these methods function1, function2, etc.

Comment: this looks like a good method for the function but for reading the name this would not work because each name is unique. (edited the name thing in answer)